# Adding CartoDb layer to Leaflet Layer Control

Tags: leaflet, cartodb

I'm trying to toggle the display of a CartoDb layer on a Leaflet map. I've been able to load the layer using this code:

```
       var layerUrl = 'http://ronh-aagis.cartodb.com/api/v1/viz/rotaryclubs_geo2/viz.json';

       var clubPts = cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl, {
           // The ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Simplify(the_geom,.01)) as geometry will store a simplified GeoJSON representation of each polygon as an attribute we can pick up on hover

           query: 'select  *, ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom) as geometry from {{table_name}}',

           interactivity: 'cartodb_id, geometry'
       })

                          .on('done', function(layer) {
                              map.addLayer(layer);

                          layer.on('featureOver', function(e, pos, latlng, data) {
                       $('.leaflet-container').css('cursor','pointer');

                       if (data.cartodb_id != point.cartodb_id) {
                           drawHoverPoint(data);
                       }
                       cartodb.log.log(pos, data);
                   });

                   layer.on('featureOut', function(e, pos, latlng, data) {
                       $('.leaflet-container').css('cursor','default')
                       removePoint();
                   });

                   layer.on('error', function(err) {
                       cartodb.log.log('error: ' + err);
                   });

               }).on('error', function() {
                   cartodb.log.log("some error occurred");
               });
```

Yet when I try to add this layer to a Layer Control:

```
       var clubs = new L.LayerGroup();
       clubs.addLayer(clubPts);
```

I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'onAdd'" error.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to load *both* `leaflet.js` and `cartodb.js` in your HTML header? This looks like the sort of error you'd get if you loaded `cartodb.js` first, and then overrode part of it with `leaflet.js`.

Answer (score 2):

A great way to reduce complexity and get up to speed quickly here would be using an already-built Leaflet plugin, like Vector Layers, that has built-in CartoDB support already. Take a look at the demo here. http://jasonsanford.github.io/leaflet-vector-layers/demos/cartodb/